# Numpy Array clips multiline string

Tags: python, numpy

I have been trying to save some multiline string in a numpy array like this:

however when i later check the content of the array it is empty

I suspect the % might be screwing me here but I dont know how to deal with it.

```
strings = np.empty(1, dtype=str) strings[0] = """         $_1 = 
    %_1.a =      25129 ± 92.3741
    $_2 = %_2.height =    11340.5 ± 1951.81
    $_3 = %_2.center =    63.4979 ± 0.275278
      $_4 = %_2.hwhm =     1.6318 ± 0.324661
    $_5 = %_3.height =    19482.3 ± 2420.92
    $_6 = %_3.center =    106.329 ± 0.12973
      $_7 = %_3.hwhm =    1.07347 ± 0.155327
    $_8 = %_4.height =    9985.67 ± 2382.35
    $_9 = %_4.center =    223.417 ± 0.257358
     $_10 = %_4.hwhm =   -1.11065 ± 0.30902
   $_11 = %_5.height =      61622 ± 2154.58
   $_12 = %_5.center =    443.983 ± 0.0458769
     $_13 = %_5.hwhm =      1.338 ± 0.0540433
   $_14 = %_6.height =    36949.9 ± 2230.42
   $_15 = %_6.center =    541.081 ± 0.0738621
     $_16 = %_6.hwhm =    1.24646 ± 0.086812
   $_17 = %_7.height =    28368.8 ± 2217.38
   $_18 = %_7.center =    693.312 ± 0.0968789
     $_19 = %_7.hwhm =    1.26497 ± 0.114331"""

print(strings[0])
```

this gives an Empty string in my case while I would expect it to print the string.

Comment: The problem is not the `%`; it's the dtype, in particular, the size of the dtype. By default, `dtype=str` can contain 1 (one!) character. Which is a single space (the first character of your text). That is what being printed. Strings (and arrays) in NumPy aren't as flexible as strings (and lists) in Python.

Comment: Given the full string, you may be better off to use a completely different structure. But without context, I can't advise you on that.

Comment: If you really feel/find that you need to put the whole piece of text inside a 1-element(!) array, simply use `strings = np.array(["""   <bunch of text>"""])`.

Comment: so basically a numpy array is just a dumb choice and i should use a list?

Comment: Depends on the context, but if your array  will never be more than, say, 1000 elements large, and your texts have varying sizes (they are not, for example, all 5 characters long), then NumPy will add little to it.

Comment: Also, given the actual content of this text, you may want to split things into rows and columns (with e.g. a "type" column, a value column and an error column), in which case Pandas might be a more logical choice. Pandas is still better with fixed byte-length entries, but it can handle strings quite a bit nicer than NumPy (that is, has nicer utilities). But overall, yes, a list of strings may work fine for your purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: strings = np.empty(1, dtype=str)
```

If I look at the result, I see that the `dtype` is 'U1'.  That's one unicode character.  `print(strings)` won't show this.  It needs to be `print(repr(strings))`, which is what `ipython` shows:

```
In [2]: strings
Out[2]: array([''], dtype='<U1')
```

Any string assigned to this array will be clipped (some argue that it should atleast give a warning):

```
In [3]: strings[0]='foobar'    
In [4]: strings
Out[4]: array(['f'], dtype='<U1')
```

We can start out with an dtype that accepts longer strings:

```
In [5]: strings = np.empty(1, dtype='U100')    
In [6]: strings
Out[6]: array([''], dtype='<U100')    
In [7]: strings[0]='foobar'    
In [8]: strings
Out[8]: array(['foobar'], dtype='<U100')
```

`np.array(['foobar']`)` will select a dtype to fit the input, but then you can't replace that with longer strings.

`numpy` isn't the best for strings.  Python strings can be any length.  Because of how it stores its data, `numpy` uses a fixed (or max) 'Un' dtype.  Otherwise it doesn't add much of its own code for handling strings.  So unless you really need the benefit of a multidimensional layout, you're better off just working with python strings and lists.

```
In [9]: ['foobar']
Out[9]: ['foobar']
```

Your multiline string is just a string with '\n'.